# Compiler Optimization - Variable Memory Usage

Tags: c++, memory-management, compiler-optimization

When I make a function most of the time I make a lot of variables inside of it, just because its easier to debug the code.

Lets say I have this function:

```
void foo(int value) {
    int x = value * 1;
    int y = value * 2;
    int z = value * 3;

    int u = x + 1;
    int v = y + 2;
    int w = z + 3;
}
```

This code is fine and its easy to debug (you can see step by step what is happening) but its using a lot of memory (28 bytes considering that each `int` is 4 bytes), and it could be optimized in this way:

```
void foo(int value) {
    int u = value * 1 + 1;
    int v = value * 2 + 2;
    int w = value * 3 + 3;
}
```

Based on this I have some questions:

1. Does the compiler make this kind of optimizations in release builds?.
2. Does it reuse the memory of variables that are not used anymore in the function to avoid using more registers?.

Comment: A real world example may be better.  As is these functions are non-ops and maybe be completely optimized away.  Do not you can always check the generated assemble to see that the compiler actually does after it compiles the code.

Comment: As soon as the function returns, though, those 28 bytes are freed up for the next function call. They're just temporarily stored on the stack (which is also pretty cheap to "allocate").

Comment: Most likely none of them will exist, since the execution of the function does not depend on their existence. Also, register allocation is a thing. Most local variables are not in memory.

Comment: "the compiler"? There are plenty of c++ compilers each with different optimizations. Also the optimizations you are asking about are known for so long that there are tons of resources to read about it...

Comment: Inspect the asm generated by your compiler in unoptimized vs optimized builds and the answer will be obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. A modern compiler will remove those intermediate variables. Yes. A modern compiler will fold constants and reuse registers and memory locations.

In short; don't worry about stuff at this level, the compiler will fix it. Instead worry about writing readable code and algorithmic improvements and leave the details to the compiler - it's pretty smart these days ;)